# Added redundant empty NameSpace while adding newly created element in somewhere middle of the xml document in java dom4j

Tags: java, xml, dom4j

I have xml template like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    <body>
        <content id="unique_id1">
        </content>
        <content id="unique_id2">
        </content>
    </body>
</root>
```

What I want to achieve is I want to insert new elements inside `content` tag by finding them by corresponding id.

Such as:

```
Element element = doc.selectSingleNode(//*[@id='unique_id2']");

Element newElement = DocumentHelper.createElement("new-element");
newElement.addText("new element text");

element.add(newElement);
```

This code can insert the `newElement` inside the specific `element`. But in `newElement`, a blank namespace is added automatically.

After insertion, the xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns="..." xmlns:xsi="..." xsi:schemaLocation="...">
    <body>
        <content id="unique_id1">
        </content>
        <content id="unique_id2">
           <new-element xmlns="">new element text</new-element>
        </content>
    </body>
</root>
```

So how to stop the empty namespace being added in the `newElement`?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the correct namespace to the new Element; in this case the same namespace as the parent element:

```
    Element newElement = DocumentHelper.createElement(QName.get("new-element", element.getNamespace()));
```